# Determining the number of single women who are not university graduates

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

In a certain government office, there are $400$ employees, there are $150$ men, $276$ university graduates, $212$ married persons, $94$ male university graduates, $151$ married university graduates, $119$ married men, $72$ married male university graduates. Find the number of single women who are not university graduates.

My attempt: I'm very skeptical about almost everything though.

Female university graduate: $276-94 =182$

married women: Married person - married men: $212-119=93$

I can assure you that I don't know what's next.

Comment: Have you tried using Venn diagrams?

Comment: You are given enough information to compute the total number of women, from which you can then determine the number of single women.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single graduate males: $94-72=22$
Non-graduate married males: $119-72=47$
Married graduate females: $151-72=79$

Single non-graduate males: $150-47-72-22=9$
Single graduate females: $276-79-72-22=103$
Married non-graduate females: $212-47-72-79=14$

Single non-graduate females: $400-9-103-14-47-22-79-72=54$

Using the rule of inclusion and exclusion, you can get there faster: $400-150-276-212+94+151+119-72=54$